# How to make the emulator "independent" in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Is there a way to run the emulator where you can drag it around instead of having it in one place like the one shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/LgRRmgfrFQM?t=395)?
[I cannot drag it around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh35r.png), and I would like to have an option that allows me to view my program in the landscape mode.

Comment: I used the View Mode > Float but I'm still having problems rotating the view to the landscape. [This](https://i.imgur.com/xuYjlLp.png)  is what happens when I do that

Answer (score 2):

It is easy. This setting can be found in the `Preferences` -> `Tools` -> `Emulator`. There you will find a checkbox named `Launch in a tool window`. You need to uncheck it. The next time you will run the emulator, it will open outside Android Studio as a new window but a new window which belongs to Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Preferences(Settings)` > `Tools` > `Emulator`

Then uncheck **Launch in a tool window**.
That's it.

[image: Emulator settings]

Comment: This is not "independent" of android studio, but in a new window that "belongs" to android studio